# Erro de "unwrapping an Optional value" na transição da tela de login

Tags: swift, exceção

Sempre que vou fazer a passagem de tela com login e senha minha aplicação para com o erro abaixo:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>
> function signature specialization  of Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()).(closure #2)

Já verifiquei os retornos das funções, se tinha algum Outlet errado, está tudo certo. Esse erro ocorreu também numa transição simples de tela, sem nenhum conteúdo, somente arrasta e puxa, não sei o que pode ser. Ele imprime o usuário e o id normalmente, mas na hora de passar para a outra tela dá erro. Segue abaixo a parte do meu código em que a aplicação para:

```
@IBAction func logar(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.myProgress.hidden = false
    self.myProgress.startAnimating()

    let parametros: NSDictionary = ["email":emailField.text!, "senha":senhaField.text!]

    controller.getLogin(parametros, handlerUser: {(usuario) -> () in
        self.usuarioAtual = usuario

        if self.usuarioAtual.msgError == "" {

            self.emailField.text = ""
            self.senhaField.text = ""

            self.myProgress.hidden = true
            self.myProgress.stopAnimating()

            let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let accessNavigation = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AccessViewController")
            LoginViewController.sharedInstance.usuarioAtual = self.usuarioAtual
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(accessNavigation, animated: true)

        } else {

            Alerta(controller: self).erro("Desculpe!", message: self.usuarioAtual.msgError)
            print(self.usuarioAtual.msgError)
            self.myProgress.hidden = true
            self.myProgress.stopAnimating()
        }
    })

}
```

Acredito que o que o Xcode está dizendo que está nulo seja o `navigationController`, mas não sei porque, uso essa mesma estrutura para passar as demais telas e funcionam, ainda ontem estava funcionando normalmente, sem alterações apareceu esse erro.

Comment: Qual linha ele mostra esta mensagem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema esta dividido em duas partes.

**1 - Valores Opcionais.**

Pode ser que este problema não esteja na sua função `add` e sim na sua classe, onde você esta declarando as suas variáveis.
Uma vez que você inicia uma variável sem valor é necessário passar o `?` para que ela se torne Opcional.
isto é, permitindo que ela fique `nill`.

**Exemplo:**

```
class MyClass{
    var a:String
    var b:String
}
```

Se você declarar desta forma em um playground notará as várias mensagens de erro dizendo que a classe em si é nula e seus atributos também, por que nenhum dos seus atributos estão inicializados.

**Assim funcionará:**

```
class MyClass{
    var a:String?
    var b:String?
}
```

Digamos que na sua função logar você tenha certeza que o field Email esteja com valor, você colocaria `!` para que ele
"acredite na sua palavra de que sim, este field possui valor", caso contratorio, dara fatal error e poderá travar o seu app.

Até ai tudo bem, é so dar uma olhada na sua classe se as variaveis estão sendo inicializadas e se não como prevenir que aconteça este problema.

**2 - Retorno da função**

Se você estiver com a intenção de fazer a função getLogin ser void o type signature deve ser declarado assim: `-> Void` e não `->()`.